# How to put a button in a table cell horizontally?

Tags: html, css

How to put a button in a table cell horizontally?

after styling radio-buttons, they moved out and began to be placed vertical

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Выпускник <a href="http:\\www.htmlacademy.ru">htmlacademy.ru</a>
            <input type="radio" name="haru" id="c1" value="yes" checked/>
            <label for="c1"><span></span>Да</label>
            <input type="radio" name="haru" id="c2" value="no">
            <label for="c2"><span></span>Нет</label>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:41px;
    height:45px;
    background:url(rad0.png);
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:41px;
    height:45px;
    background:url(rad1.png);
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Remove the outer `<label>`, it serves no apparent purpose.

Comment: According to MDN you're not allowed to put descendant labels inside a `label`. You may use a `span` instead, if you *must*. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: There are no buttons in your code.